# What are the topics of string theory that are comprehensible with only a mathematical background on Manifolds and Algebraic Topology?

Tags: string-theory, mathematical-physics, mathematics, differential-geometry, topology

What are the topics of string theory that are comprehensible with only a mathematical background on manifolds and algebraic topology? Also, I have read only the first four chapters in Peskin & Schroder. And I have studied QM.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1603/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27051/2451

Comment: Thanks , I just want to know the topics i mentioned above with a list of introductory reference material for self study. For eexample I know that Calabi-Yau Manifolds are vital in string theory research . What are the references for Calabi-yau and other topics that are useful for someone with very limited QFT background but have studied Geometry and topology?